# Comparing $n^n$ and $n!^2$

Tags: inequality

I tried to prove that if $n>2$ then $(n!)^2>n^n$ but did not managed. That is the trick to compare those as both grows rapidly? Induction seems hard: $((n+1)!)^2=(n+1)^2(n!)^2>(n+1)^2n^n$ but why $(n+1)^2n^n>(n+1)^{n+1}$? I also noted that $n^n=e^{n\ln n}$ and $n!^2=e^{2\ln n!}=e^{2\sum_{i=1}^n \ln i}$ but got stuck.

Comment: [Stirling's approximation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1553748/comparing-nn-and-n2) takes care of this quickly, if you're allowed to use this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note:

$$n!^2 = (1\cdot n)\cdot (2\cdot(n-1))\cdots(n\cdot 1)$$

Prove that $k\cdot (n+1-k)\geq n$, for $k=1,2,\dots, n$. So $$n!^2\geq n^n$$

With $n>2$, we have $2\cdot (n-1)>n$, so it is strict inequality when $n>2$.

Comment: Do you use induction & the symmetry of the function to prove the lemma or is there a better way?

Comment: I'd use calculus - it follows from the shape of $f(x)=x(1-x)$, which is increasing when $x<1/2$ and decreasing when $x>1/2$. Use that to show that $f\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\leq f\left(\frac{k}{n+1}\right)$, then multiply by $(n+1)^2$. But I'm sure there are more direct ways to prove it.

Comment: For $k$ between $1$ and $n$, $((n+1)-k)\cdot k = \left(\frac{n+1}{2 }+\frac{n-2k+1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{n+1}{2}-\frac{n-2k+1}{2 }\right)=\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{n-2k+1}{2} \right)^2\ge\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)^2=n$, and the inequality is strict if $k$ is strictly between $1$ and $n$.

Comment: Nice. Yeah my method was slightly different using induction on $k$. $(k + 1)(n + 1 - (k+1)) = k(n + 1 - k) + n - 2k$. For all $k \leq \frac{n}{2}$ this works by induction. But since the function is symmetric around $\frac{n}{2}$, we immediately get that the inequality also holds for all $k \geq \frac{n}{2}$ also.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose
$(n!)^2 > n^n$.
Then
$((n+1)!)^2
=(n!)^2(n+1)^2
>n^n(n+1)^2
$
so we need
$n^n(n+1)^2
\ge (n+1)^{n+1}
$
which is the same as
$n^n
\ge (n+1)^{n-1}
$
or,
dividing by
$n^{n-1}$,
$n 
\ge (1+1/n)^{n-1}
$.
Multiplying by
$1+1/n$,
this becomes
$n+1
\ge (1+1/n)^n
$.

This is true because
$(1+1/n)^n
< e
$,
as has been shown many times here.
Here is one of the easier:

Using the binomial theorem,

$\begin{array}\\
(1+1/n)^n
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(1/n)^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}(1/n)^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(n-j)}{k!n^k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(1-j/k)}{k!}\\
&<\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}\\
&<\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}\\
&= e
\end{array}
$

Actually,
all we need is
a bound on 
$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}
$.
An easy one
is gotten from
$k! \ge 2\cdot 2^{k-2}$
for $k \ge 2$,
easily proved by induction.
Then

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}
&=1+1+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}\\
&\lt 2+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2\cdot 2^{k-2}}\\
&\lt 2+\frac1{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^k}\\
&= 2+1\\
&= 3
\end{array}
$

Comment: Minor quibble: you should write $(1+1/n)^n<\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} < \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} = e$.

Comment: I put that in when you weren't looking.